# Calculating a value and adding it to a map

Tags: clojure

I have a list of maps:

```
(def mylist
  [{:id 1 :sub [{:subid 1} {:subid 2}]}
   {:id 2 :sub [{:subid 3}]}])
```

I want to add a new key/value pair to each map element of the list that contains the count of items in `:sub`:

```
[{:id 1 :sub [{:subid 1} {:subid 2}] :subcount 2}
 {:id 2 :sub [{:subid 3}] :subcount 1}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are your brackets off here? Looks like you intend the :subcount key to appear in the top-level map, not inside the vector associated with the :sub key.

Comment: You are right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In clojure, "adding to a map" is done with assoc, which returns a new map with the specified value(s) added, and usually if you want to do the same operation on a collection of things, you use the `map` function.

```
(defn subcount
  "return the number of items in the :sub of m"
  [m]
  (count (:sub m)))

(defn add-count
  "add subcount to the given map"
  [m]
  (assoc m :subcount (subcount m)))

(defn add-counts
  "add subcount to all the objects"
  [objects]
  (map add-count objects))

(def mylist
  [{:id 1 :sub [{:subid 1} {:subid 2}]}
   {:id 2 :sub [{:subid 3}]}])

(add-counts mylist)
=> ({:sub [{:subid 1} {:subid 2}], :subcount 2, :id 1} {:sub [{:subid 3}], :subcount 1, :id 2})
```

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation. Thanks!